# Background URLs into array

Tags: jquery

I have a container with a few divs. Each div has a background image. I need to get URL from each image into an array

```
<div id="images">
    <div style="background-image: url(79cbf113f.jpg)" class="thumb" title=""></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(234234234.jpg)" class="thumb" title=""></div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>

$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
    var img = $('#images .thumb').attr("src");
});
```

How do I get those?

Comment: @trincot updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` over divs and get corresponding css property using `.css`. You could also process the property using regex.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
    console.log(
      $('#images .thumb').map(function(){
        return $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\("(.+)"\)/, '$1')
      })
      .toArray()
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
    <div style="background-image: url(79cbf113f.jpg)" class="thumb" title=""></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(234234234.jpg)" class="thumb" title=""></div>
</div>

<button class="button">Collect Images </button>
```

Comment: Cool. I just need image names, without a path. Just do replace? Thanks

Comment: Then you could use some native DOM code `this.style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\("(.+)"\)/, '$1')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `get`:

```js
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
    var images = $('#images .thumb').map(function () {
         return this.style.backgroundImage;
    }).get();
    console.log(images);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
    <div style="background-image: url(79cbf113f.jpg)" class="thumb" title=""></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(234234234.jpg)" class="thumb" title=""></div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```